# What is difference between Project level "Java Compiler" and Windows Preferences level "Java"->"Compiler" in Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors

In Eclipse, When we click on any project and then we Click on Project in the top bar -> Java Compiler -> Building ->  Click Apply 
then file import of Projects added in the build path of selected projected gives issue "The import #### cannot be resolved."

However, when we go to Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Compiler -> Building -> Click Apply
then it don't give any such issue.

My question is: what is the difference between these two compiles and how it behave differently?

Comment: Going through Window -> Preferences sets workspace default settings.  Going through Project -> Properties will set project specific settings that may be used instead of the workspace defaults.  You must have something different between the two of those.

Comment: That Project specific setting should also build the projects associated with it. I am unable to find the difference as it is working in workspace defaults but not in the project specific. I am trying to run the JUnit test cases.

Comment: What are you doing on the 'Building' page? All that page does is set how build errors are handled. It has nothing to do with the build path.

Comment: I am trying to run the JUnit test case using Run as JUnit Test. At that time build is done by Eclipse.